# After switching from 32 GB of RAM to 64 GB, WSL2 still refuses to use more than 32 gigs?

Tags: memory, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, out-of-memory

I'm on Windows 11, using WSL2 (Windows Subsystem for Linux). I recently upgraded my RAM from 32 GB to 64 GB.

While I can make my computer use more than 32 GB of RAM, WSL2 seems to be refusing to use more than 32 GB. For example, if I do

```
$ python3
>>> import torch
>>> a = torch.randn(100000, 100000) # 40 GB tensor
```

Then I see the memory usage go up until it hit's 30-ish GB, at which point, I see "Killed", and the python process gets killed. Checking `dmesg`, it says that it killed the process because "Out of memory".

Any idea what the problem might be, or what the solution is?

Comment: Post the contents of your .wslconfig file located here: C:\Users\<your_user_name>\ it’s probably a hidden file

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72693871/1114253
Basically, WSL2 only allowed using half the memory by default, and you have to update (or create) your .wslconfig file to make it higher.